# SoftLayer API: Change quote name

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there a method to call that changes the name of a Quote? I have used getRecalculatedOrderContainer method to get the actual container, but when saved that with Product_Order.placeQuote(container) the new quote get its name autogenerated.

Answer (score 0):

When you place the quote you should be able to set the name for the quote, take a look at the container documentation:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order

it has a parameter called "quoteName" you need to set that value with the name that you want.

Regards